# Getting Error in openerp-7 for time.strftime

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, strftime

I am getting below error while I am upgrading my asset module:

openerp.tools.safe_eval: Cannot eval u"{'search_default_year':1,'search_default_this_month':1,'search_default_asset_category':1, 'search_default_posted':1, 'search_default_purchase_date': time.strftime('%Y-01-01'), 'group_by':[], 'group_by_no_leaf':1}"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/7.0/server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 241, in safe_eval
    return eval(test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode), globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'unquote' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Please suggest me what causes it. I appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Comment: did you  imported time in your .py file

Comment: I do have import time on my .py file